# magento 2.3.0 issue with WYSIWYG editor with special characters in URL

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I have issue on magento 2.3 issue with WYSIWYG editor fails to parse directives of files with special characters in URL

```
<img src="{{media url=&quot;504928.jpg&quot;}}" alt="" />
```

Please check this screenshot : https://prnt.sc/lql08u

any have idea how to resolve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like you've copied and pasted it somewhere that has converted the single quotes to html.  I've just added that to a cms page on 2.3.0 - with wysiwyg off, and;

```
&quot;
```

corrected to

```
'
```

like this;

```
<p><img src="{{media url='504928.jpg'}}" alt=""></p>
```

And it's saved correctly

[image]

Comment: thanks , but i think it's not perfect solution.